# How to highlight focus switch widget in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Can someone tell me how to show highlight `switch` widget when I set focus on `Switch`?It should be look like focused.

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (200, 150)


class User(Screen):
    swtch = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.swtch_focus, 1)

    def swtch_focus(self, *args):
        self.swtch.focus = True



class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
User:
    swtch: swtch
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Switch:
                id:swtch
```

Answer (score 0):

There is hoverableBehaviour in github here is the link https://gist.github.com/KeyWeeUsr/3166f13d363d5558f481d538c6a5d2aa copy the code and create a module to your current directory and import it to use it which you can add to your Widget to have the on focus or highlight feature. This is how to do.

```
class Highlight(HoverBehavior,Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        print('Focus on')
    def on_leave(self):
        print('Focus off')
```